# Is it possible to set the UIAccessibilityFrame for an UI control (eg UIButton) from xib file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I need to set an accessibility frame for the UIButton that is different then the normal button frame. The problem is I have access to just the xib file and I can not modify the .h or .m implementation file. Is there any way I can set the accessibility frame different then the view frame from xib file?

Comment: y do u want to increase/decrease the accessibility frame for an element?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set accessibility frames in Interface Builder. Note that accessibility frame is specified in **screen coordinates**. The Interface Builder doesn't know how is the view positioned on the screen (which is different on every device) and the frame is always dynamic (e.g. different during a call due to different height of the status bar).

If you need a different accessibility frame, I recommend to use a `UIButton` subclass and then use that subclass in your xib.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the view's Identity Inspector (option + command + 3). The Accessibility settings are toward the bottom.

Comment: I don't see the frame there.

Comment: Do you mean you want the button's parent view to act as the accessibility button?